# Typescript interface Generics : Allow generic T only if T is of union type 'A | B'

Tags: typescript, generics

```
export type Message = [
    {
        id: 'message',
        settings: ComponentSettings;
    }
];

type Industrial = [
    {
        id: 'title',
        settings: ComponentSettings;
    },
    {
        id: 'text',
        settings: ComponentSettings;
    }
];
```

I'd like to allow T, only if T is 'Message | Industrial'

```
export interface CardRef<T> {
    id: 'Industrial' | 'Message';
    childInstances?: T;
}
```

Comment: What's the point in a generic that can only take a single value?

Comment: @jonrsharpeim not following

Comment: I want the what's passed to T to be either Message or Industrial

Comment: @Relm *"I want the what's passed to T to be either Message or Industrial "* is a very different statement from *"I'd like to allow T, only if T is 'Message | Industrial'"*. If you really mean the former, I suggest editing the question so it says that, rather than the other.

Comment: You can change the declaration to  `interface CardRef<T extends Message | Industrial>` but the example code makes me wonder if you should just use a type alias that is itself a union and not an interface.  You want that `id` property to correspond to a particular choice of `T`, right?

Comment: @jcalz just asked another question with better syntax.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may want `CardRef` to be a union type rather than a type with a generic parameter:

```
export type CardRef =
    {
        id: 'Industrial';
        childInstances?: Industrial;
    }
    |
    {
        id: 'Message';
        childInstances?: Message;
    };
```

Usage:

```
let x: CardRef = { id: 'Industrial' };
x.childInstances; // type is Industrial | undefined

let y: CardRef = { id: 'Message' };
y.childInstances; // type is Message | undefined
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=32&ssc=1&pln=37&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwDKFjAJYoDmAzlALxQDeAvgNwBQ9EAHsgE7BSiRQCyExYgENC0CgG16UaVSkz5eACYAuKAHIEA4aLUAaOfOnEc%20IsVXwkqdFhMESDedXoBdBvW7QAkikUBXYmA2PCEAG3IoSXlKA0MlVTV8YFCIPVj5Y1x7c1hEZDQMbCyzRxlqfWj0mXj1YBZgNMMZTNMSCzzrQrsS2Oc3RhZ2Tk9YITZFACUIADNyWJim6Rq1H39A4LC1UqaAYwALPFDFH0ChFB2BAH5VVYCgkNDtqGd5AB95qqWVdX5BEVSnvJ9odjihTucrqpftoIE86IwUpxmBYxpMZhFKFBlrd1g81M8GMwAHTAo4nYBnC7EWhQAD0tK44GgeFIOPuYSgrygfl8MwIEEUCJwUBAKPGU1mFExy2h-3x8JAJIOZLBFIh1LpDJGLL4Wn%20nO5vOm-MFQA)